# Reputation Points and badges on answers

Tags: discussion, answers

Is it really necessary to display the Reputation point and badges on Answers? Wouldn't you agree that the reputation somehow influence in the selection of the answer?

Comment: If you're going to propose that it not be shown, then the burden would be on you to demonstrate that it *does* influence readers in a negative manor.

Comment: @Servy what is the purpose of showing it originally?

Comment: Presumably to give it some value, so that people would want to earn it.

Comment: "Wouldn't you agree that the reputation somehow influence in the selection of the answer?" Isn't that the whole point of reputation?

Comment: Is it @BoltClock?

Comment: It's the way the site displays an individual, with [flair](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/what-are-badges). While some may be influenced by the show of badges/reputation (like you) others aren't. Moreover, I would value input from someone with an honour roll... they've been around, and most likely will be well-versed on the topic. No?

Comment: Not showing reputation of the **asker** of the question would make more sense to me. Of course I want to know if the community trusts the answerer.

Comment: @Wooble but I thought up votes and down votes were created to crontrol the value of the answers?

Comment: Using the reputation isn't the wrong point of reference. Wouldn't be better to use just up votes and down votes

Comment: Well, sure, but if a troll with 1 rep and someone with 500K give me contradictory answers to a question, I shouldn't have to wait for others to come along and up/downvote to know which one to try first.

Comment: Just curious why this hasn't been closed due to being off-topic? It doesn't have anything to do with SO specifically, but the entire Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen it should be moved, not closed. From the blog announcement "When in doubt, you can always post your question on your local meta. If it’s clearly relevant to the engine or network as a whole, we’ll move it."

Comment: Thanks @aurbano, I appreciate your words and understanding in regards with the question presented.

Comment: @aurbano: Then the question that should be asked is probably "why even have a reputation system?"

Comment: @BoltClock this is not about extremes. The question is about if you think it is necessary to show it in the answer. Taking into consideration the influence this may have on the selection of the answer.

Answer (score 9):

No, it is not *necessary* to display the reputation points or badges *anywhere* on the site. Yes, I would agree that it *might* sometimes impact how an answer is evaluated by the OP or the community. This isn't necessarily always a bad thing.

However, as the network has been built on users obtaining badges and reputation I imagine it'd be fairly difficult to do away with. The user card is everyone's bragging rights and so will be fiercely defended! Do you have any data that would provide a reason for removing it?

It's also a signature for every post, it helps you see how created the post and to distinguish between people with the same name more easily.

Comment: That it isn't always a bad thing authority (high rep) is deferred to is not in doubt. Far more interesting though is whether that is the right thing to do, because sometimes a lower-rep user's answer who provided a better answer is thus ploughed under. Especially nice if the accepted answer has possible security holes. Still, there's no system without downsides.

Comment: Of course it won't always be the right thing to do @Deduplicator... I'm not sure that it happens as often as people assume though; it could be the tags I'm most active in. Unfortunately people are easily led :-(.